# gnu sed trying to use OR operator with groups but not working

Tags: sed

Im using this sed command to parse a string to get `my-team`

```
echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' | gsed "s/origin.*bitbucket.org\(:\)\(.*\)\/.*/\2/"
```

But I want to use the or operator to match ":" or "/". Its throwing an error I dont understand:

```
echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' | gsed -r "s/origin.*bitbucket.org\(:|\/\)\(.*\)\/.*/\2/"
gsed: -e expression #1, char 45: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

gsed version:

```
gsed --version
gsed (GNU sed) 4.7
```

Comment: with the `-r` option you enable extended regular expressions where `\(` is a *literal parenthesis character* not a capturing group. Omit the backslashes for the capturing parentheses. Ref [https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-regular-expressions.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\2` indicates print the second match, if your target is to print `:my-team` (not clear from your question) then you can do this:

```
echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' |\
 gsed "s/origin.*bitbucket.org\(:.*\)\/.*/\1/"
```

To still match in case either  `:` or `/` is present you can can use non-matching groups. Instead of `(<regex>)` these are written as `(:?<regex>)`:

```
echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' |\ 
gsed -r "s/origin.*bitbucket.org(:?:|\/)(.*)\/.*/\2/"
```

This will produce `my-team` for both:

- 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)'
- 'origin git@bitbucket.org/my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)'

I think the confusion originates because in sed to separate the command you can use any character (often you will see /) this requires that you escape that character within the regex. So if you are not aware of this it is not clear what to escape. If you use `,` instead of `/` then this character does not need to escaped:

```
echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' |\
 sed -r "s,origin.*bitbucket.org(:?:|/)(.*)\/.*,\2,"
```

And you actually do not need the `:?` if you are certain one of the two characters (`:` or `/`) will always be present.

Comment: target to print is "my-team" without colon an I want to match ":" or "/" there

Comment: You already accomplish that with the first command. If you are just interested in learning what is wrong with your second command is probably that the regex is not finding a second match

Comment: I want to match `'origin git@bitbucket.org:my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)'` or `'origin git@bitbucket.org/my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)'` and get `my-team`

Comment: Also, why did you add the -r flag on the second case? Check the manual to see what that does

Comment: im using OR which require -r because its extended i thought

Comment: I understand now. So first when you do extended syntax, groups are not escaped, i.e., you write `(` instead of `\(`. To get what you want you can just  use non-matching groups.

Comment: hmm your last edit still doesn't do what Im trying. I want to match for ":" or "/". this doesn't return "my-team": `echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org/my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' | gsed -r "s/origin.*bitbucket.org(:?:)(.*)\/.*/\2/"`. note the "/" instead of ":". I want to account for both

Comment: ahh nevermind i see this works `echo 'origin git@bitbucket.org/my-team/myrepo.git (fetch)' | gsed -r "s/origin.*bitbucket.org(:?\/)(.*)\/.*/\2/"`

Comment: Yes I misunderstood, I think I finally got what you were after in my last edit.